# Android - Access file from assets \ PDF display

Tags: java, android, android-intent, assets

I am trying to retrieve a reference to a file stored in the `assets` directory to a file named `myfile.pdf`. I have tried to do it as follows:

```
File file = new File("android_assest/myfile.pdf);
Log.d("myTag", "" + file.isFile());
```

Somehow, I get `false` when the `myfile.pdf` do exists in the `assets` directory. I verified it using `getAssets().list("")` and `Log.d()` each element in the returned array.

More of which, I am trying to get a reference to a PDF file and then use any PDF viewer, which is already installed on the device, in order to view the PDF.

I guess that since the previous issue (retrieving a reference to the file) returns `false` then the next snipped code fails:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/myfile.pdf"));
startActivity(i);
```

Anyone has a clue why I am unable to retrieve a reference to the file? and why I cannot use already installed PDF viewer to display a PDF (after retrieving a reference to the PDF file)?

Thanks.

Comment: Check [how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As Barak said you can copy it out of assets to internal storage or the SD card and open it from there using inbuilt pdf applications.

Following Snippet will help you.
(I have updated this code to write to and read files from internal storage.

But i dont recommend this approach because pdf file can be more than 100mb in size.

So its not recommended to save that huge file into internal storage

Also make sure while saving file to internal storage you use

```
openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Then only other applications can read it.

Check following snippet.

```
package org.sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SampleActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        CopyReadAssets();

    }

    private void CopyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "git.pdf");
        try
        {
            in = assetManager.open("git.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/git.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure to include

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

in manifest

Comment: +1, I should have posted something similar in my answer as the OP specifically asked about opening it with other apps.

Comment: How can I write the file into the internal storage (since I do not have a SD card)?

Comment: @VipulShah GREAT Solution and code snippet!!!! Who knew viewing local PDFs in Android would be such a pain! In iOS its a 1 liner!!

Comment: @Vipul Shah:  Document path is not valid.. while opening.. in fact its not even writing that pdf on to sdcard.. please help..

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that.  There is no directory structure in an apk, it is just data.  The framework knows how to access it (`getAssets`), but you cannot look for it as a file in a directory.

You can open it as an input stream...

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(myfile.pdf)));
```

Or you can copy it out of assets to internal storage or the SD card and access it there.

Comment: But I able to do so for HTML files. E.g., I can access HTML files within the `assets` directory and view them on a `WebView`.

Comment: Took me a bit of searching, but I found out why.  The URL "file:///android_asset/" doesn't point to a particular directory, it is only used by WebView to address assets. Pulled that from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3281337/1105376)

Answer (score 0):

like say [Vipul Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758104/vipul-shah), but in the case for external.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        copyReadAssets();
    }


    private void copyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        String strDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ File.separator + "Pdfs";
        File fileDir = new File(strDir);
        fileDir.mkdirs();   // crear la ruta si no existe
        File file = new File(fileDir, "example2.pdf");



        try
        {

            in = assetManager.open("example.pdf");  //leer el archivo de assets
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)); //crear el archivo


            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator + "Pdfs" + "/example2.pdf"), "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

change parts of code like these:

```
out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

the before example is for Pdfs, in case of to example .txt

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```