# android: BufferUnderflowException while rendering pdf

Tags: android, pdf, bufferunderflowexception

I am trying to implement a program to read pdf file but when I am doing so I am not able to show the pages in first time and in second time its showing few pages with overlapping words.I dont understand what is wrong Could anyone suggest me what to do?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] pdflist;
File[] imagelist;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    System.out.println("images" + images);
    imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
        }
    });
    pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
        pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
    }
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
    openPdfIntent(path);
}

private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
    try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
        intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Logcat details:**

```
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123): null
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123): java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at java.nio.Buffer.checkGetBounds(Buffer.java:177)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:41)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at java.nio.MappedByteBufferAdapter.get(MappedByteBufferAdapter.java:144)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:384)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at net.sf.andpdf.nio.NioByteBuffer.get(NioByteBuffer.java:99)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.decode.FlateDecode.decode(FlateDecode.java:68)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.decode.PDFDecoder.decodeStream(PDFDecoder.java:92)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.PDFObject.decodeStream(PDFObject.java:334)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.PDFObject.getStreamBuffer(PDFObject.java:307)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.dereference(PDFFile.java:272)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.PDFObject.dereference(PDFObject.java:686)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.PDFObject.getDictRef(PDFObject.java:508)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.findPage(PDFFile.java:1696)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.getPage(PDFFile.java:1569)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity.showPage(PdfViewerActivity.java:779)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity.access$12(PdfViewerActivity.java:769)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity$3.run(PdfViewerActivity.java:259)
02-04 13:14:09.232: E/PDFVIEWER(1123):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Second class :**

```
package com.syntel.pdfviewer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;

public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}

public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}

public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}

public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/*
 * public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.ic_launcher;
 * }
 * 
 * public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return
 * R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
 * 
 * public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }
 * 
 * public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }
 * 
 * public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }
 * 
 * public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }
 */
}
```

Comment: Your this code seems to be correct. Please post the code for next activity.

Comment: @shree202could you suggest me why is it happening so?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

lets use `PDFViewer.jar` file from below location:

http://www.filecrop.com/pdf-viewer.jar.html

Just let me know if it worked for you.

**Update:**

If you want to load file from asset folder, simply get the path to that folder like:

`File mFile = new File("file:///android_asset/yourFilename.pdf");`

Comment: I am not getting any jar file from that link what should I do then

Comment: @poojagupta Try this Url: http://www.mediafire.com/download/2wcdnzmd1yi/PDFViewer.jar

Comment: thanks,I want it to keep pdf in assets folder and read using pdfViewer is it possible to do so.

Comment: First let me know if this jar works for you or not. And Yes ofcourse, you can get file loaded from assets folder.

Comment: when i downloaded it I didnt got any jar file its a zipped file with some java classes

Comment: how is it possible !!! i tried just now and am able to download. Can i send you the file through mail or any other way ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46851/discussion-between-shree202-and-poojagupta)

Comment: You can remove the email id now.

Comment: sorry I am in office I cant do it now

Comment: No problem. Just remove the comment containing your mail id.

Comment: could you suggest me how to proceed next

Comment: Would you please send the link from where you got this project ? I'll try to solve the problem from home. Now, its time to leave the office. I'll update my answer here if i found the solution.

Comment: I got it from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980852/android-access-file-from-assets-pdf-display?rq=1.

Comment: Thanks,I actually want that pdf should be in assets folder and we can read it without adobe or any other reader.Please help me out

Comment: Did you got anything?