# PDF file path is incorrect

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-studio, filepath

I want to open a PDF file in my application but something goes wrong everytime.
Yeah , I watched many topics about it, however none of them helped me.

Here are some photos of the error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZpO2.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuoeM.jpg]

```
 btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
                                    File file = null;
                                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/raw/" + "tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    if(file.exists()) {
                                        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                                        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                                        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
                                        try {
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                            // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File path is incorrect." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
    );
```

Maybe the error is that I put these files in ***/raw*** ? Should I store them in ***assest folder*** instead?

Comment: This error is because your path file is incorrect. Where are you placing your PDFs files?

Comment: http://imgur.com/wzY3Urv

Comment: now i get this -> http://i.imgur.com/Hi18Be3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your this line

```
 file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/raw/" + "tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");
```

with this line

```
 file = new File("android.resource://com.cpt.sample/raw/tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jKrwPKh.jpg now i get this

Comment: Replace com.cpt.sample with your package name

Comment: if u can't give static package name then place this line File file = new File("android.resource://+" + getPackageName() +"/raw/tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");

Comment: i changed into full path : 
file = new File("android.resource://com.example.dovydas.myapplication3/res/raw/tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");
still path is bad

Comment: com.example.dovydas.myapplication3 is this AndroidManifest.xml file package name?

Comment: File file = new File("android.resource://+" + getPackageName() +"/raw/tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf"); just place this line and try because i think so com.example.dovydas.myapplication3 this is not a package name

Comment: i think so.. http://i.imgur.com/DdOV4Xz.jpg

Comment: are you try File file = new File("android.resource://+" + getPackageName() +"/raw/tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");  this code??

Comment: Yes i did, the path is wrong

Comment: move your pdf from row to Assets folder and change path from raw to Assets and try this one definitely work

Comment: Would be worth trying to create the uri like so: `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.dovydas.myapplication3/res/raw/tirepressure‌​monitoringsystem3.pdf")` and pass that to the intent. Rather than going through a file object. No idea if it will work though...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to access file from **raw folder** @gdd.
 
 Since while compiling your android project R.java file is get genrated , you can access whatever in your raw folder by ***R.raw.fileName*** and in your case you want to access the file name tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf, So You can use ***R.raw.tirepressuremonitoringsystem3***.
 
 
If You dont wnat to go this way and want to use jdks file api .. [this question will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name) 
Thanks and keep coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use raw if you want to access it by a identifier at runtime:

```
R.raw.tirepressuremonitoringsystem3
```

Use assets if you want to access it by string name.

Either way you will need to copy it out of your app to a location another app has access to, as detailed in these answers:

- [Android - Access file from assets \ PDF display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980852/android-access-file-from-assets-pdf-display)
- [How to open a pdf stored either in res/raw or assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  where i should enter this code? in activity_main.xml any line?

Comment: In the manifest http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html